# Showing results from two separate queries together

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have to show data from two different queries together.

Query 1:

```
select count(DISTINCT(nickname)) users_got_a_card from capture_captive where `number_successed`>0;
```

Query 2:

```
select count(DISTINCT(`nickname`)) users_shown_captive from `capture_captive`;
```

I want to show the data from both these queries together.

Comment: Together - i.e. sum of values? Or in two rows?

Comment: Can you not use the UNION operator? "The UNION operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more SELECT statements."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them as two columns of a single row you can try

```
SELECT 
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(nickname))  
      FROM capture_captive 
      WHERE `number_successed`> 0
) users_got_a_card,
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`nickname`))  
      FROM `capture_captive`
) users_shown_captive
```

or

```
SELECT users_got_a_card, users_shown_capt
  FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(nickname)) users_got_a_card 
      FROM capture_captive 
      WHERE `number_successed`> 0
) a CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`nickname`)) users_shown_capt
      FROM `capture_captive`
) b
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(IF(`number_successed` > 0, `nickname`, NULL))) users_got_a_card,
       COUNT(DISTINCT(`nickname`)) users_shown_capt
  FROM `capture_captive`
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ec5d/5)** demo

Answer (score 3):

depending on what you need you can do someting like this
per column:

```
select ( select count(DISTINCT(nickname)) users_got_a_card from capture_captive where 'number_successed'>0) as column1,
 (select count(DISTINCT(`nickname`)) users_shown_captive from 'capture_captive')as column2
```

or per row:

```
select count(DISTINCT(nickname)) users_got_a_card from capture_captive where number_successed>0 
UNION ALL  
select count(DISTINCT(nickname)) users_shown_captive from capture_captive
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(DISTINCT(case when `number_successed`>0 
           then `nickname` end)) users_got_a_card, 
       count(DISTINCT(nickname)) users_shown_captive
from capture_captive
```

Answer (score 0):

That's simple.

First, get the result from the first query usual way and store it in a variable called `$var1`,
Next, get the result from the second query usual way and store it in a variable called `$var2`,
And finally, create a code to show them together:

```
echo $var1," ",$var2;
```

As simple as that.